# check multiple keys in sessionStorage for condition

Tags: javascript, html

I need to check if 3 keys in sessionStorage are equal to completed.  Is there a built in parameter or function of sessionStorage that allows me to check if 3 keys are equal to completed.  Here are some examples of what I've tried.

this first example is small and clean, but I do not think I can pull more than 1 key at a time so the code breaks.

```
if (sessionStorage.getItem("lessonOne", "lessonTwo", "lessonThree") === "completed") {
        SetSCOComplete();
    } else {
        alert("Course not complete");
}
```

I've also tried iterating through the array but this doesn't seem efficient.

```
for (var i = 0; i < sessionStorage.length; i++) {

    var key = sessionStorage.key(i);

    var value = sessionStorage.getItem(key);

    console.log('Key: ' + key + ', Value: ' + value);

    var num_matches = value.match(/d/gi).length;

    if (num_matches <= 3) {
            SetSCOComplete();
        } else {
            alert("Course not complete");
        }
    }
}
```

If there's a better way to handle this, I'd like to know more about the options.  thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make an array of the lessons that need to be completed and pass that into [Array.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) where you check the sessionStorage.

```
var courseComplete = ["lessonOne", "lessonTwo", "lessonThree"].every(
  lesson => sessionStorage.getItem(lesson) == "completed"
);

console.log(courseComplete); // true or false
```

Answer (score 0):

one option to resolve this:

```
var allCompleted = true;

for (var i = 0; i < sessionStorage.length; i++) {
    var key = sessionStorage.key(i);
    var value = sessionStorage.getItem(key);

    if (value !== "completed") {
        allCompleted = false;
        break;
    }
}

console.log(allCompleted ? "Course Complete" : "Course Not Complete" );
```